# Dim out other components when UIPickerView is active

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

In my little iPhone application, I created `UITableView` with a `UIPickerView` which dynamically slides up when a `cell` is tapped. Since I don't want users to tap other `cell` when choosing value in the `UIPickerView`, I hope to make it less distractible by dimming out all the other components (the table, the title bar, etc). Kind of like what [isolator](http://willmore.eu/software/isolator/) does.

I think there might be some api method does this, but I can't find it. Any thoughts are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

When a cell is tapped you can add another uiview and set its alpha 0.5 and keep uipickerview above it so the background will look dimmed.

Answer (score 0):

If you have call back methods for presenting the picker, then you can disable and enable the user interaction of the root view of the view controller.